# optaplanner project job scheduling example - cannot compile successfully when switching to drl file

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to reuse the project job scheduling example in the 7.4.1.Final distribution. I changed `projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml` file to use

`<scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>`

instead of `<incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.ProjectJobSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator</incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>`.

To be clearer:

I only change this part of  `projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml` file:

```
<scoreDirectorFactory>
  <!--<incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.ProjectJobSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator</incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>-->
  <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
</scoreDirectorFactory>
```

But then I encountered compilation error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/solver/projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl, line=95, column=0
   text=Rule Compilation error The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) Comparable]
---
Warning Messages:
---
Info Messages:

at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:507)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolver(CommonApp.java:103)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:97)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:84)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:80)
at org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.app.ProjectJobSchedulingApp.main(ProjectJobSchedulingApp.java:34)
```

I did not modify the `projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl` file, but here is the file content:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver;
    dialect "java"

import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.bendable.BendableScoreHolder;

import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.Allocation;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.ExecutionMode;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.Job;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.JobType;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.Project;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.ResourceRequirement;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.domain.resource.Resource;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.capacity.NonrenewableResourceCapacityTracker;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.capacity.RenewableResourceCapacityTracker;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.capacity.ResourceCapacityTracker;
import org.optaplanner.examples.projectjobscheduling.solver.score.drools.RenewableResourceUsedDay;

global BendableScoreHolder scoreHolder;

// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "nonrenewableResourceCapacity"
    when
        $resource : Resource(renewable == false, $capacity : capacity)
        accumulate(
            ResourceRequirement(resource == $resource,
                    $executionMode : executionMode,
                    $requirement : requirement)
            and Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode);
            $used : sum($requirement);
            $used > $capacity
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, $capacity - $used);
end

rule "renewableResourceUsedDay"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        ResourceRequirement(resourceRenewable == true, $executionMode : executionMode, $resource : resource)
        Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode,
                $startDate : startDate, $endDate : endDate)
    then
        for (int i = $startDate; i < $endDate; i++) {
            insertLogical(new RenewableResourceUsedDay($resource, i));
        }
end

rule "renewableResourceCapacity"
    when
        RenewableResourceUsedDay($resource : resource, $capacity : resourceCapacity, $usedDay : usedDay)
        accumulate(
            ResourceRequirement(resource == $resource,
                    $executionMode : executionMode,
                    $requirement : requirement)
            and Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode, $usedDay >= startDate, $usedDay < endDate);
            $used : sum($requirement);
            $used > $capacity
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, $capacity - $used);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "totalProjectDelay"
    when
        Allocation(jobType == JobType.SINK, endDate != null, $endDate : endDate,
               $criticalPathEndDate : projectCriticalPathEndDate)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0,  $criticalPathEndDate - $endDate);
end


rule "totalMakespan"
    when
        accumulate(
            Allocation(jobType == JobType.SINK, $endDate : endDate);
            $maxProjectEndDate : max($endDate)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, -$maxProjectEndDate);
end
```

Have anyone encountered similar issue? Any clue how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the steps you provide, to reproduce the problem, but I don't encounter any problems. From the exception throwed, it says that you have some issue in the drools file (projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl) line 95. Do you change something in that drools file? It will be better if you post your drools file here, so I could help you better.

Comment: @the.wizard thanks for your reply. I updated my post by adding the drools file.

Comment: The error message says `projectJobSchedulingScoreRules.drl, line=95`

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet  I tried removing the rule on `totalMakespan` and it works. But I did not modify this rule, also I don't see any problem with this rule.

Comment: I tried to compare your drl file with mine, and yes they are identical. Could you please tell me all changes that you have made to the original project job scheduling example? I think the clue are somewhere in there.. Oh and I wonder, what java version you're using?..

Comment: I am using `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1`

Comment: I just updated my post with the code modifications I did.

Comment: The error is related to the use of  `max($endDate)` in the rule `rule "totalMakespan" `. I change it to  `sum($endDate)` and it works. However, it is logically wrong to do so. Is there any alternative way to fix this issue?

Comment: @PeakWu : I don't see the code modifications you made. It's really strange, since I tried using exactly the same version of example, and everything just working fine. It probably better if you tried this : 1. Download again a new fresh optaplanner distribution (I prefer the zip one). 2. Import the source example to your favorite IDE (I using eclipse). 3. Only alter the projectJobSchedulingSolverConfig.xml to change from IncrementalScoreCalculator to ScoreDrl. It should be running good if you follow this steps. Do you done any other beside those steps? Please post it here what those steps are.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is:

> The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) Comparable

This is a result of a limitation of the `max()` Drools accumulator function, which is not generic and its return type is always `Comparable` even if you feed it with `Integer` argument. Therefore the type of the `$maxProjectEndDate` variable is `Comparable` (which is not a number) and so you cannot negate its value using the `-` operator.

As a quick fix, you can cast it to `Integer` before negating it in the `totalMakespan` rule:

```
scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, -((Integer) $maxProjectEndDate));
```

Comment: Fixed on master: http://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/commit/845ee9525

Answer (score 1):

As yurloc explain, the result of max() drools accumulation function was a comparable object, and that's why it can't be negated using the - operator. This answer just another alternative to yurloc answer :

```
rule "totalMakespan"
    when
        $maxProjectEndDate : Number() from accumulate(
            Allocation(jobType == JobType.SINK, $endDate : endDate);
            max($endDate)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, -$maxProjectEndDate.intValue());
end
```

Comment: This is a valid approach too. Small improvement suggestion: you can even collect Integers directly (like $i : Integer() from accumulate(...)) to avoid the intValue() call later.